# Load balance when two servers connected to different switches on pox controller

Tags: load-balancing, sdn, mininet, openflow, pox

I have load balancer application that balance between two servers connected on two different switches [the topology like the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Tpn.png)
when I send traffic from the first domain and the selection was the server from the second domain, only the syn packet arrived then RST is sent from the client to the server

the code of the balancer is:

```
def handle_request_on_server2 (self, packet, event, server):

   "Handling request on server2"

   msg = of.ofp_flow_mod()
   msg.idle_timeout = IDLE_TIMEOUT
   msg.hard_timeout = HARD_TIMEOUT
   msg.buffer_id = None
   msg.priority= 500
   msg.data = event.ofp # Forward the incoming packet

   msg.match.in_port = event.port
   print "in_port = ", event.port
   msg.match.dl_src = packet.src
   print "packet src mac = ", packet.src
   msg.match.dl_dst = LOAD_BALANCER_MAC
   msg.match.dl_type = ethernet.IP_TYPE
   msg.match.nw_src = packet.next.srcip
   msg.match.nw_dst = LOAD_BALANCER_IP 

   # Append actions
   # Set the dst IP and MAC to load balancer's
   # Forward the packet to server's port
   msg.actions.append(of.ofp_action_nw_addr.set_dst(server.ip))
   msg.actions.append(of.ofp_action_dl_addr.set_dst(server.mac))
   msg.actions.append(of.ofp_action_output(port = server.port))
   print "output port = ", server.port
   self.connection.send(msg)

   "  Install reverse rule from server2 to the client in domain1 "

   msg = of.ofp_flow_mod()
   msg.idle_timeout = IDLE_TIMEOUT
   msg.hard_timeout = HARD_TIMEOUT
   msg.buffer_id = None
   msg.priority = 500

   msg.match.in_port = 1
   msg.match.dl_src = server.mac
   msg.match.dl_dst = packet.dst
   msg.match.dl_type = ethernet.IP_TYPE
   msg.match.nw_src = server.ip
   msg.match.nw_dst = packet.next.srcip

   # Append actions
   # Set the src IP and MAC to load balancer's
   # Forward the packet to client's port
   msg.actions.append(of.ofp_action_nw_addr.set_src(LOAD_BALANCER_IP))
  msg.actions.append(of.ofp_action_dl_addr.set_src(LOAD_BALANCER_MAC))
   msg.actions.append(of.ofp_action_output(port = event.port))

   self.connection.send(msg)
```

when I see the flow table on the two switches, I see the flows installed correctly. can anyone tell me what is the problem?